# Crawl the images and save only the selected images

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I wrote a program to crawl through any website and provide the name of the images present in the website. The user can select the images from the list which they want to save. The images gets downloaded but the image file cannot be opened. I added the function for save image. The GUI is done in Tkinter I guess that is not required.

```
      def fetch_url():
        url = _url.get()
        config['images'] = []
        _images.set(())

        try:
            page = requests.get(url)
        except requests.RequestException as rex:
            _sb(str(rex))
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            images = fetch_images(soup, url)
            if images:
                _images.set(tuple(img['name'] for img in images))
                _sb('Images found: {}'.format(len(images)))
            else:
                _sb('No images found!.')
            config['images'] = images


    def fetch_images(soup, base_url):
        images = []
        for img in soup.findAll('img'):
           src = img.get('src')
           img_url = ('{base_url}/{src}'.format(base_url=base_url, src=src))
           name = img_url.split('/')[-1]
           if name[-3:] == "png" or name[-3:] == "jpg" or name[-4:] == "jpeg": ### <- here
               images.append(dict(name=name, url=img_url))
        return images


    def fetch_selected_images(event):
        widget = event.widget
        selected_idx = widget.curselection()
        selected_items = [widget.get(int(item)) for item in selected_idx]
        selected_images = []
        url = _url.get() + '/img'

        for img in selected_items:
            img_url = ('{base_url}/{src}'.format(base_url=url, src=img))
            name = img_url.split('/')[-1]
            if name in selected_items:
                selected_images.append(dict(name=name, url=img_url))
            for idx in selected_idx:
                widget.itemconfig(idx, fg='red')

        config['images'] = selected_images

        def save():
    if not config.get('images'):
        _alert('No images to save!')
        return

    if _save_method.get() == 'img':
        dirname = filedialog.os.getcwd()
        _save_images(dirname)


def _save_images(dirname):
    i = 1
    if dirname and config.get('images'):
        for img in config['images']:
            img_data = requests.get(img['url']).content
            filename = str(i)
            i = i + 1
            with open(filename + '.png', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(img_data)
        _alert('Done')
```

Comment: what about your download function? did you set format as it was?

Comment: I converted the images into pngs and saved it in current working directory

Comment: Can you provide full script ? Lot of variables are missing and there is not calls to a functions

Comment: I added the functions required

Comment: Download and install `wget` then pass the url for the image into it and it will download the image directly to your directory or any directory that you want.